# Probability of drawing when only replacing some draws

Tags: probability

You can draw $4$ attributes A, B, C and S. The attributes A, B and C are not replaced, e.g. you can only draw these attributes once. The attribute S can be drawn infinitely.

I want to calculate the probability of getting the attribute C with 2 draws.

Calculating the probability of not drawing C, I have for the first draw $3/4$ chance, and for the next draw there is either $3/4$ or $2/3$ depending on what I drew the first time (drawing A or B would remove that draw from the pool, but getting S would keep it in the pool). Hence I get:

$ \mathbb{P}(C) = 1 - \frac{3}{4}\cdot \left( \frac{1}{3} \cdot\frac{3}{4} + \frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{2}{3}\right) = 0.479$

However, if I look at the total combinations for $2$ draws, there is the following $13$ draws:

AB, AC, AS, BA, BC, BS, CA, CB, CS, SA, SB, SC, SS

$13$ total combinations, where $6$ of those have drawn C, which is $0.461$.

**A simulation of the draws gives me $47.9\%$ so why is the bottom one wrong?**

Comment: Those combinations are not equally probable.  $CS$, for instance, has probability $\frac 14\times \frac 13$ while $SC$ has probability $\frac 14\times \frac 14$.

Comment: A reason why the combinations aren't equally probable is because the two draws are not independent events like rolling a die twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This illustrates a common error in discrete probability:  It's not always the case that each event is equally probable.

Here, for instance, events of the form $XY$, where $X\in \{A,B,C\}$ and $Y\in \{A,B,C,S\}$ with $X\neq Y$, each have probability $\frac 14\times \frac 13=\frac 1{12}$, since the $X$ is withdrawn from the pool after it is observed. On the other hand, events of the form $SY$, where $Y\in \{A,B,C,S\}$, each have probability $\frac 14\times \frac 14=\frac 1{16}$ since the first $S$ is not withdrawn from the pool after being observed.

To repair the second calculation, note that the relevant events $AC,BC, CA,CB,CS$ each have probability $\frac 1{12}$ while $SC$ has probability $\frac 1{16}$.  Thus the answer is $$5\times \frac 1{12}+\frac 1{16}=\frac {23}{48}=.4791\overline 6$$